# Storyboard - UILabel auto shrink not working

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, uilabel

Within a storyboard, setting autoshrink to minimum font scale works fine when I run my app on iOS7.

However, when I switch to running it on iOS6, the auto shrink doesn't work.

It also appears to be setting the font size of the label to 14 regardless of what I specify in the storyboard>label>font.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, when I specified my UILabel to have the line breaks set to "Truncate Middle", it worked as expected.